# Display gender in alternating male female format for a table using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So I have this table and I am trying to sort it such that the values of the 'Sex' column are alternating. Below is the table in question

```
+--------------------+------+---+
|       Employee_Name|salary|Sex|
+--------------------+------+---+
| Adinolfi, Wilson  K| 62506| M |
|Ait Sidi, Karthik...|104437| M |
|   Akinkuolie, Sarah| 64955|  F|
|        Alagbe,Trina| 64991|  F|
|    Anderson, Carol | 50825|  F|
|   Anderson, Linda  | 57568|  F|
|     Andreola, Colby| 95660|  F|
|         Athwal, Sam| 59365| M |
|    Bachiochi, Linda| 47837|  F|
|  Bacong, Alejandro | 50178| M |
|Baczenski, Rachael  | 54670|  F|
|     Barbara, Thomas| 47211| M |
|    Barbossa, Hector| 92328| M |
|Barone, Francesco  A| 58709| M |
|       Barton, Nader| 52505| M |
|       Bates, Norman| 57834| M |
|    Beak, Kimberly  | 70131|  F|
| Beatrice, Courtney | 59026|  F|
|       Becker, Renee|110000|  F|
|       Becker, Scott| 53250| M |
+--------------------+------+---+
```

The question posed to me is to write a statement such that :

```
+---+-------+
|sex|EMpName|
+---+-------+
| M |Kevin  |
| F |Carol  | 
| M |Josh   |
| F |Linda  |
| M |Sam    |
| F |Sam    |
+---+-------+
```

Please help, any hints or concepts would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, can you explain a bit more the logic that allows to go from the input table to the output?

Comment: The input is the first table. The required output is the second table, I need to write a statement that displays male and female employees in alternating order. @Steven provided an answer and it worked. Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add an "order" column to get expected result. Here is a solution with `row_number`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

# assuming df is your dataframe

df.withColumn(
    "ordering",
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("sex").orderBy(F.lit(1))),
).orderBy("ordering", "sex").drop("ordering").show()
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you so much! So we partition by the sex and the row number function generates the row numbers for male and female separately, and then we order by sex and ordering column. Could you please let me know what the orderBy(lit(1)) does?

Comment: @MashedPotoatoes Honestly, I did not try my code. I felt like I needed an order clause, but you can try to remove it. If it does not make an error, it should give exactly the same result. Otherwise, it means that you need to order against a column, and I'm just ordering here against the value 1 for the whole column (creating a fixed value column on the spot with `lit`).